# How to convert Date based on String value for TimeZone

Tags: java, date

I have a Date Object which I need to convert to the logged in user's timezone. The problem is that the timezone is represented in our DB simply as a String value of GMT plus or minus the offset in hours. So for example "GMT" or "GMT-5" for New york time or "GMT+5".

How can I convert my Date Object to the User's time when all I have are String like "GMT-3" or "GMT+5"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you able to change your database structure? If you're just storing an offset, it would be sensible to store that as a number instead - and bear in mind that not all offsets will be whole numbers of hours. Also note that an offset isn't the same as a time zone. There can be multiple time zones which currently have the same offset, but will have different offsets at other times.

Comment: Also, the Date object shouldn't have to be "converted". A Date object is timezone agnostic. You should only care about the time zone when formatting a Date to a String, or parsing a String to a Date.

Answer (score 2):

An example should help, but it seems a 1 character [ISO 8601 time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone):

```
String myDate="2001-07-04T12:08:56GMT-3";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT'X");

if (myDate.indexOf("GMT-") >= myDate.length() -1 -4) {
    myDate = myDate.replace("-","-0");
}
if (myDate.indexOf("GMT+") >= myDate.length() -1 -4) {
    myDate = myDate.replace("+","+0");
}

System.out.println(format.parse(myDate));
```

it should work.

- the `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT'X` is compliant with iso8601 time zone
- `myDate = myDate.replace("-","-0");` adjusts the date to your format

Comment: Good example. But please keep in mind that SimpleDateFormat is NOT ThreadSafe. When using DB connections you often have a pool of threads and can run into "strange behaviour" because of the missing thread safety.
I would recommend FastDateFormat, which works exactly like SimpleDateFormat but has built in thread safety: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html

Comment: Yes SimpledateFormat is not thread safe since a synchonization could cause loss of performance and making a new instance is faster then synchonization. FastDateFormat should be a good opportunity, but it doesn't support iso8601 ....

Answer (score 1):

## Offset ≠ Time Zone

As Jon Skeet said in comment, a time zone is more than just an offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT. Storing the offset hours (and minutes) is a less-than-optimal strategy for handling date-time in your database/storage.

## Joda-Time

The java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use  [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Or, in Java 8, use the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), defined by JSR 310, and inspired by Joda-Time but re-architected.

We can create a [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) to represent the offset, but as noted this does not make a complete time zone logically.

We can pass a java.util.Date object directly to a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor. Along with that we pass a [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object. To go the other direction of conversion, call `toDate` on a DateTime object.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); // Retrieved from elsewhere. Faked here.

String offsetInput = "GMT-5";
int offsetHours = 0, offsetMinutes = 0;
offsetInput = offsetInput.replace( "GMT", "" ); // Delete 'GMT' characters.
String[] parts = offsetInput.split(":"); // About splitting a string: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/642706

// Handle results of split.

if( parts.length == 0 ) {
    // Add some error handling here
} 

if ( parts.length >= 1 ) {
    offsetHours = Integer.parseInt( parts[0] ); // Retrieve text of first number (zero-based index counting).
}

if ( parts.length >= 2 ) {
    offsetMinutes = Integer.parseInt( parts[1] ); // Retrieve text of second number (zero-based index counting).
}

if( parts.length >= 3 ) {
    // Add some error handling here
} 

DateTimeZone partialTimeZoneWithOnlyOffset = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes( offsetHours, offsetMinutes );

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, partialTimeZoneWithOnlyOffset );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "date: " + date ); // BEWARE: JVM's default time zone applied in the implicit call to "toString" of a Date. Very misleading.
System.out.println( "partialTimeZoneWithOnlyOffset: " + partialTimeZoneWithOnlyOffset );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime with alternate formatting: " + DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( Locale.US ).print(  dateTime ) );
```

When run…

```
date: Sat Feb 08 22:40:57 PST 2014
partialTimeZoneWithOnlyOffset: -05:00
dateTime: 2014-02-09T01:40:57.810-05:00
dateTime with alternate formatting: Sunday, February 9, 2014 1:40:57 AM -05:00
```